# Plot Circles in GeopPandas with a ground-radius: results are not correct

Tags: python, geopandas

I try to plot flight distances on a map. In order to do this, I need to respect the projection of the map of course.

It seems that the circles are somehow distorted --> looks like a projection

It is just that the result does not make any sense, the circles I create are too small.

On the example below: the West-Coast should be within the circle (4800km) around New York City.
But it clearly is not.

I cannot find any comment in GeoPandas that the circle (buffer) shall not be used for something like this.

```
import geopandas as gpd

lat = 33.975
lon = -118.405

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

data=[]
dic={}

dic["lat"]= lat
dic["lon"]=lon
dic["city"]="SFA"
data.append(dic.copy())

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data)

df["geometry"]=gpd.points_from_xy(df.lon, df.lat)

df["center"]=df["geometry"]

df.crs="EPSG:4326"   # initiat a CRS

df = df.to_crs("epsg:3395")     # change to 3395 for circle creation

df["geometry"]= df.geometry.buffer(4800*1000)   #4800km range

df=df.to_crs("EPSG:4326")    #switch back to orginal CRS


ax = df.plot(facecolor='none', edgecolor='red',figsize=(15,15))     #plot circle
df.center.plot(ax=ax,color="r")                                     #plot center point
world.plot(ax=ax,alpha=.5)                                          #plot map
```

[image]

- I played around with differen coordinate systems. But I never get the desired result.
- I also tried to create the buffer/circle using angles in the EPSG:4326 CRS and haversine formula. --> identical result, circle is too small

Comment: Mercator exaggerates distances further from the equator. So in general a buffer created using Mercator will be too small. You could try an equidistant projection centered on your point of interest.

Comment: using a circular buffer in any projection will always create circles in that projection... not actual circles on a sphere (or an ellipsoid)...  you could have a look at the [Pyproj.geod](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/geod.html) module on how to calculate points on geodesic lines... or checkout my answer on how to do it with EOmaps

Answer (score 2):

you might be interested in giving [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) a try...

I guess it provides all the functionalities you're seeking :-)
(Note however that there's a bug if you want to draw geodesic circles that extend outside the crs-bounds...)

```py
from eomaps import Maps

x = [-60, -40, 40, 70]
y = [-60,  40, 70, 20]

m = Maps(Maps.CRS.Mollweide())
m.add_feature.preset.land()
m.add_feature.preset.ocean()

m.set_data(data=None, x=x, y=y, crs=4326)
m.set_shape.geod_circles(radius=2e6)
m.plot_map(fc="none", ec="r", set_extent=False)

m.add_line(xy=list(zip(x, y)),
           mark_points="ro",
           connect="geod",
           color="r", lw=1, ls="--",
           )
```

[image]